# If ${z_{n}}$ sequence of complex numbers converges to $z$. Does ${Arg(z_{n})}$ converge to Arg(z)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

If ${z_{n}}$ sequence of complex numbers converges to $z$. Does ${Arg(z_{n})}$ converge to Arg(z)?

How to prove?. I   took $ Arg(z_{n})=\tan^{-1}(Im(z_{n})/Re(z_{n}))$, my proof is using the continuity of $arctan$ function. How to prove using definition of convergence?
I have  one doubt consider $z_{n}= 1+\frac{e^{(π/4)}}{n}$, if $n$ is even and $z_{n}= 1+\frac{e^{(-π/4)}}{n}$ if $n$ is odd . In this case how this result holds? $Arg(z_{n})$ is an oscillatory sequence, isn't it? Please help me.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91131/why-there-is-no-continuous-argument-function-on-mathbbc-setminus-0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$Arg(z_n)$ doesn't necessarily converge to $Arg(z)$.

For example taking the sequence $z_n = -1 - (1/n)i$. $z_n\to -1$ and $Arg(-1) = \pi$ whereas $Arg(z_n) \to -\pi$.

(Assuming arg is taken in the usual range $(-\pi,\pi]$)

Answer (score 0):

For a sequence $\{z_n\}$ converging to $z$, it is not true in general that $Arg(z_n)$ converges to $Arg(z)$.

Take any sequence converging to $0$,for example $z_n= \dfrac{1}{n}$. In this situation, $Arg(z_n)=0$, but $Arg(0)$ is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as z $\not=$0 and Argz$\not=O $, so $Argz=\theta\in (0,2\pi) $.  For there would be a sector containing z with $z_n $staying outside the sector for large n...  You could take a ball centered at z and inside the sector, outside which the sequence stays for large n, contradicting convergence. ..  I believe such a region is called a *slit domain*...